# "Class 'Auth' not found" in file of public folder

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have 2 files in public folder. The first generates json via php and second java script to fill the php file in the views.
The proble is that i need to pass the logged user name to the json php file.
The error is this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Auth' not found in C:\WEB\vhosts\blog\public\datatableeditor\data.php:168 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\WEB\vhosts\blog\public\datatableeditor\data.php on line 168
```

after this  i add

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

and the next error is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth' not found in C:\WEB\vhosts\blog\public\datatableeditor\data.php:169 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\WEB\vhosts\blog\public\datatableeditor\data.php on line 169
```

How to navigate to the class?

Comment: in your code in controller or blade file use this: `\Auth::guard('web')` it using auth and no need to `use` that, like this: `$user=\Auth::guard('web')->user();`

Comment: in public folder, the file is not with blade template. I use this code `Auth::user()->name` and the error above appears.

Comment: does the `auth()->user()->name` helper function work ? or does it also give errors

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function auth()

Comment: You can't just add php files to public/ and expect them to work with the framework, you're bypassing all of the laravel bootstrapping and middlewares by doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it short, `Auth` class is autoloaded by composer. Therefore you need to require it's `autoload.php` file. Based on directory structure you've provided it should look something like this in your `data.php`:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
```

That being said, it won't help you, because facades need Laravel's service container to be initialized first to work. Check official documentation on Laravel's [directory structure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/structure). You should **never expose your PHP files in `public` folder** - that is plain wrong and can lead to severe security problems. If you want to use Laravel's services then you need to organize your project properly.

If you want some PHP logic to be accessible by URL you create *route* and link it up with specific *controller's action* and then put your PHP logic inside that controller.

This way Laravel's `index.php` can process your request, boot all framework parts properly and handle it.

Comment: Yes i think is wrong too. But I cant  figure it out how to call the json output of this php file if i put it in views dir and name it with blade template from the javascript file that is in bublic folder `"ajax": "../datatableeditor/data.php?job=get_companies"`

Answer (score 2):

Laravel is an MVC framework. The proper way to handle this is to use routes and controllers, you should never be creating php files in the public directory if you want them to be a part of the application.

Even if you autoloaded the vendor files and bootstrapped laravel, you'd be missing the middlewares that authenticate users.  I recommend you read through all of the docs and read up on MVC before using Laravel.